# handling escape/back button in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

is there a way to know when the android system keyboard is released. i have some textinput field in my app. when the textinput is selected the keyboard goes up. pressing the escape/back button on the android makes the keybord disappear. i need to know when the keyboard has disappear so that i can call a function. so my question is how to you find out when the keyboard release was due to the escape button.

my second question: is there a way to send the kivy app to the background when the escape button is pressed.  from my research i have seen:

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('kivy', 'exit_on_escape', '0')
```

which prevents the app from closing but what if i want the app to be sent to the background.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to look at this [pull request](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/pull/4670).

Comment: Will do. Thanks for the reply